# Selecting element which .each() function runs on

Tags: jquery

I've this piece of code but am getting that `elem` is not defined. also tried `this` and `$(this)` but got the document instead.

I should mention that $('.listop') is an array of jquery objects (that is why I use each). before each listop element their is a radioOption element and I need that for each of them, when a person click on "listop", the "radioOption" will get checked.

```js
let inputs = $('.listop');
$(document).ready(function() {
  inputs.each(function(int, elem) {
    elem.click(function() {
      elem.closest('.radioOption').prop('checked', true);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radioOption" name="distribution[only]" value="6" data-id="lonly"></td>
  <td> לנמען יחיד</td>
  <td>
    <div id="lonly" class="listop" style="display: inline;">
<input type="text" name="mobile">
```

Comment: The whole block can be replaced with: `$('.listop').click(function() { $(this).closes('.radioOption').prop('checked', true); });`

Comment: remove that each function, and try again. Also put $(this) instead of elem

Comment: Closest is not likely ok. I cannot imagine a checked property on a parent of an input. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55143024/edit) and then `[<>]` and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @BenM when I try your code, this = window...

Comment: @atarixdev you need to put the HTML in code not in image

Comment: @mplungjan is that better? can't think of anything else that is relevant

Comment: @atarixdev see my answer for a proper snippet

Comment: @atarixdev of course code is better then an image, we can't copy your code from an image (easily) to use in our answers or for testing. Snippets are the way to go for html/css/js problems since they often can reproduce your issue making it clear for others what problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean this

1. Find the tr parent of the input
2. find the checkbox with class .radioOption in that row and check it

NOTE, the event handler will work on ALL .listop inputs and ONLY check the checkbox in the same row

```js
$(function() {
  $(".listop input").on("click",function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").find('.radioOption').prop('checked', true);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radioOption" name="distribution[only]" value="6" data-id="lonly"></td>
    <td> לנמען יחיד</td>
    <td>
      <div id="lonly" class="listop" style="display: inline;">
        Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radioOption" name="distribution[only]" value="6" data-id="lonly"></td>
    <td> לנמען יחיד</td>
    <td>
      <div id="lonly" class="listop" style="display: inline;">
        Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radioOption" name="distribution[only]" value="6" data-id="lonly"></td>
    <td> לנמען יחיד</td>
    <td>
      <div id="lonly" class="listop" style="display: inline;">
        Mobile: <input type="text" name="mobile">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I Revised the question so it will be clear that each() is nessecery. I have a several <tr> the contains similar code. Also thank you very much for the correction

Comment: I saw, it did work. thank you so much. my question is why? how come it is effecting all "listop" elements without a loop?

Comment: That is jQuery assigning the event handler to the collection of `$(".listop input")` one reason why we like it